# How do I search PPT slides for a string of indeterminate length?

Tags: vba, string, powerpoint, wildcard

I need to find and replace a string in PPT. But the length of the string will vary and PPT does not allow wildcard searches like Word. I need to find every string that begins with `<REF` and end with `>`. In Word I would search for `<REF*>`. How do I do this in PPT? Here is what I have so far, but this only finds some of the strings. Please help!

```
Function FindAndReplace(s As String, replacementText As String) As String
  Const LEFT As String = "<REF"
  Const RIGHT As String = ">"
  Dim temp As String
  temp = s
  Dim iPos As Integer
  iPos = 1
  Dim iStart As Integer, iEnd As Integer
  Do
    iPos = InStr(iPos, temp, LEFT)
    If iPos = 0 Then
      FindAndReplace = temp
      Exit Function
    End If

    iStart = iPos
    iEnd = InStr(iStart, temp, RIGHT)
    If iEnd = 0 Then
      FindAndReplace = temp
      Exit Function
    End If

    Dim targetText As String
    iEnd = iEnd + 1
    targetText = Mid(temp, iStart, iEnd - iStart)
    temp = Replace(temp, targetText, replacementText)
    iPos = iPos + Len(LEFT) + Len(targetText) + Len(RIGHT)
If iPos >= Len(temp) Then Exit Do
  Loop
  FindAndReplace = temp
End Function
```

Comment: Have you considered [regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)?

Comment: Getting all the text from ppt may be a uphill task. Here is good [reading](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00274_Export_Text_to_a_text_file-_extract_text_from_PowerPoint_-Mac_or_PC-.htm). Even  the example does not cover all the type of shapes that may conatain text.